# Lebesgue measurable function on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Imagine $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a increasing function. First prove that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, is it Riemann integrable?

Comment: What's a "Riemann measurable" function?

Comment: sorry I edited my question @sam

Comment: in general lebesgue integrable doesn't imply Riemann integrable. But increasing functions on a compact interval will be both Lebesgue and Riemann integrable (the set of discontinuities of an increasing function has Lebesgue-measure zero).

Comment: why a compact interval is Riemann integrable? @peek-a-boo

Comment: An interval is an interval; you can't talk about it being integrable, only functions can be integrated. The point I was trying to make is that because the interval is compact, and $f$ is increasing, it has a maximum and minimum ($f(1)$ and $f(0)$ respectively), so in particular it is bounded. Also, the set of discontinuities of an increasing function has measure zero (this is a fairly standard result which you can easily google). FInally, it's a classic theorem which says a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if it has a discontinuity set of measure zero

Comment: how can we prove function is Lebesgue measurable?@peek-a-boo